# Insert new element in JsonArray

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I have a JsonArray which is composed of many arrays. I need to insert a new element at the beginning of each of those arrays.

I tried to traverse it to extract each of the arrays and insert the new element but it does not work.

I tried to traverse it to extract each of the arrays and insert the new element but it does not work.

```
for (int i=0; i<consultaArray.size();i++)
   {
    JsonElement elemento = consultaArray.get(i);
        JsonObject item = new JsonObject();  
        item.addProperty("Prueba", "Prueba");
 }
```

The structure is `[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{....},....]`

It should insert a new element in each of the JsonArray arrays

Comment: Well, you're not doing anything with `elemento` and `item` so what do you expect to happen? Assuming you want to add `item` to `consultaArray` you'd have to shift all elements to the right by one and then set the element at index 0. However, `JsonArray` objects might already provide methods to add elements at specific indices.

Comment: Which library do you use, `Gson`? How your input `JSON` looks like? Something like this: `[[{"a":1,"b":2}, {...}, ...],[{"a":3, "b":4}, ...]]`? Could you show us input `JSON`? Do you want to add the same new node ot each array?

Comment: 'it does not work' doesn't mean anything. What library are you using? What is the exception?

Comment: Yes, i'm using gson and the structure is that, [[{"a":1,"b":2}, {...}, ...],[{"a":3, "b":4}, ...]].
Yes, i need add the same value
it should be [[{"c":3,"a":1,"b":2}, {...}, ...],[{"c":3,"a":3, "b":4}, ...]]

Comment: If I understand correctly you changed each `JSON` object on first place in each array by adding new property: `"c":3`. So, you do not want to ad new object. You want to add new property to existing object at `0-index` in each array. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I use Gson 2.8.5 for this code

```
String jsonArrayStr = "[[{'key1':'value1'},{...}],[{'key1':'value1'},{...}]]";

JsonArray consultaArray = (JsonArray) new JsonParser().parse(jsonArrayStr);
JsonArray finalJsonArray = new JsonArray();

for (JsonElement arrEl : consultaArray) {
    JsonArray elemento = (JsonArray) arrEl;
    JsonArray finalArr = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject item = new JsonObject();
    item.addProperty("Prueba", "Prueba");

    finalArr.add(item);
    for (JsonElement el : elemento) {
        finalArr.add(el);
    }

    finalJsonArray.add(finalArr);
}
```

---

Final array

```
[[{"Prueba":"Prueba"},{"key1":"value1"},{...}],[{"Prueba":"Prueba"},{"key1":"value1"},{...}]]
```

I insert new element in start point on array. If you don`t need this, delete cycle "for" and use youJsonArray.add()

Comment: It backs to the next error 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray
in line 
JsonArray elemento = (JsonArray) arrEl;

Comment: @FranciscoJavierBonilloPonce You remove element {...}? My full jsonArrayStr "[[{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'}],[{'key1':'value1'},{'key2':'value2'}]]" work great.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example,zdadco I have done the following:

```
         JsonArray consultaArray = getFields(querySQL);         
         JsonArray finalJsonArray = new JsonArray();

         for (JsonElement arrEl : consultaArray) 
         {              
            JsonObject obj = arrEl.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonObject item = new JsonObject();
            JsonArray finalArr = new JsonArray();                                      
            item.addProperty("Test", "Test");
            finalArr.add(item);
            finalArr.add(arrEl);
            finalJsonArray.add(finalArr);   
        }
```

And the result is:
Before `[[{"ID":"70","Org":"Townhall","..",.....}]]`
After : `[[{"Test":"Test"},{"ID":"70","Org":"Townhall","..",.......}]]`